# Mips Firmware - Jumping out to another segment

Tags: mips

I am in the process of reverse engineering mips firmware.  The firmware is big endian , 32bit processor.  I have successfully extracted and unzipped the firmware.  Now I am in the process of writing custom mips code in another segment of the flash.  Here are the changes to the current mips firmware:

Old Code:

```
80010000 lui $v0,0x502e
80010004 lw $v0,-0x2302($v0)
80010008 lw $a0,0x4($v0)
8001000C jal 0x80010024
```

New Code: (to jump to new segment, j and jal will not work, only jr will work)

```
80010000 lui $t4,0xb010
80010004 ori $t4,$t4,0xa100
80010008 jr $t4
8001000C nop
```

Then in the new segment:  (b010a100)

I just jump right back for now: (jumping back past the 8001000C nop instruction)

```
B010A100 lui $t4,0x8001
B010A104 ori $t4,$t4,0x0010
B010A108 jr $t4
B010A10C nop
```

So far everything is ok except, since I took out some instructions:

```
80010000 lui $v0,0x502e
80010004 lw $v0,-0x2302($v0)
80010008 lw $a0,0x4($v0)
8001000C jal 0x80010024
```

How would I add them correctly in the new segment? (B010A100)  Thanks.